# Parse tableview and pointers

Tags: uitableview, parse-platform

I'm trying to populate the cell.textlable.text in the tableview with a "created by" object related to the current user. What I'm getting is the lessons for all users.

Here's what I have:

```
    - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithClassName:@"Lessons"];
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // The className to query on
        self.parseClassName = @"Lessons";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        self.keyToDisplay = @"Player";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = NO;

        // The number of objects to show per page
        self.objectsPerPage = self.Lessons.count;
    }
    return self;
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Lessons"];
    [query includeKey:@"Player"];
    [query includeKey:@"name"];
    [query includeKey:@"updatedAt"];
    [query includeKey:@"createdBy"];

    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
    if (self.objects.count == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }


    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

    return query;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                        object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Lessoncell";

    PFTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[PFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
```

Here's where I need to put all the players related to the current user, not just all the players created by every user.

```
    PFObject *player = object[@"Player"];

    NSLog(@"%@", player);

    [player fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *player, NSError *error) {


        cell.textLabel.text = player[@"name"];

        NSDate *updated = [object updatedAt];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM d, h:mm a"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lesson Taken: %@", [dateFormat stringFromDate:updated]];

    }];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What's the actual problem though? What's not working?

Comment: So I have a `user` class for a club and `players` class for that particular club. I'm trying to return all the players related to the user, not all the players for all clubs, which is what its doing now. Maybe it's simple, but my brain is bleeding.